# Transformer test only making sense unloaded

Tags: transformer

I have a problem in testing a transformer recovered from an old wall wart. The transformer has several secondary taps: the wall wart had a slide switch allowing the selection of four different dc outputs via a bridge rectifier and capacitor.

I connected the ground clip of my oscilloscope to the transformer wire that had connected to the common of the switch, then connected the probe tip to each other wire in turn to measure voltages. The resulting voltages made sense, for example a 10.6Vrms waveform was measured for the tap that had provided 12Vdc.

The problem arose when I tried to measure the voltages under load, as in the previous measurements I had simply placed the scope across the secondary taps directly.  To do this, I connected a 1k resistor across the highest tap (10.6Vrms as above).  This was a light load and well within the maximum rated secondary current of 1A.  I then connected my scope across the resistor. I expected to see a somewhat lower voltage under load, but measured a flat 0V.

I can make no sense of this result, and feel it must be a basic misunderstanding. I have tried other smaller and larger loads of 10k and 100R with the same result.

Below is a diagram of the setup. I am omitting the other secondary taps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIMWJc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Edit:** The comments helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you remove the 1k resistor do you still measure 0V? I'm guessing that you may have blown a fuse or damaged the transformer.

Comment: Steve G, on removing the load resistors and measuring across the transformer with the scope, I get the same expected 50Hz sinewaves as before.

Comment: Here is some info that may help. In the loaded test as drawn above, if I leave the ground clip unconnected and only attach the probe at the point shown, I get a messy jagged sinewave of roughly the expected amplitude. As soon as I attach the ground clip to the indicated position, flat 0V.

Comment: You did not by accident switch the scope to 50Ω input impedance?

Comment: Good thinking, that's instructive. No I definitely didn't.

Comment: Disconnect the transformer from the mains, and measure the resistance of the 12V secondary. If its a few Ohms or less its OK, but anything higher means your transformer is damaged.

Comment: @replete: you are definetly doing something wrong, so maybe give some more details. Maybe even a photo. Scope type, crosscheck with a multimeter, give people data input to trigger the right paths in their brains ;)

Comment: It seems strange that the common of the switch was ever connected to the transformer. I would have expected that the switch common would be connected to one of the output wires leading from the wall-wart, with the other wire connected back to the transformer.

Comment: @brhans: most such wallwarts I know just switch in resistors to configure a 317

Comment: @Steve G, thanks. I measured the resistance and it was over 20k. I ensured that I stripped off the enamel before measuring. I started to unwind the transformer and found some heat damage to the tape. These were the only tests I did on the transformer and I'm highly confident I never shorted it, so I guess I have discovered why the wall wart was thrown out.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, thanks for your suggestions. Sorry to report it seems I wasn't doing as much wrong as imagined though!

Comment: @PlasmaHH :O a 317 ?? You must have expensive wall-warts ... The ones I'm familiar with switch between different secondary taps on the transformer and are completely unregulated.

Comment: @brhans: I don't think they make them anymore as even small smps seem to be cheap enough. I would however think that maybe a 317 and a bunch of resistors is cheaper than a multitap  (typically they had 1.5,3,6,9V sometimes more switches) transformers.